# Java Swing JTextArea and BufferedReader

Tags: java, swing, filereader

Can someone explain me why my app start to freeze if I try to add a text to JTextArea after reading a file by BufferedReader?

Ok. I use a GUI Designer and I have this class

```
public class ReaderTest {
private JPanel rootPanel;
private JTextArea textArea;
private JButton readButton;
private File file;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Reader");
        frame.setContentPane(new ReaderTest().rootPanel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}

private ReaderTest() {
    readButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        file = new File("/path/to/6.3MBfile");
        new Thread(new FileReader()).start();
    });
}

class FileReader implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        reader1();
//        reader2();
    }

    private void reader1() {
        try (InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
            int count;

            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            while ((count = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                str.append((char) count);
            }

            textArea.setText(str.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void reader2() {
        try (InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {

            String line;
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line);
            }

            textArea.setText(str.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

If I read a file by BufferedInputStream (reader1), I don't have any freezes. But If I read it by BufferedReader (reader2), I get some freezes. Furthermore, my PC start to freeze after one minute and I can't simply stop my app.

Comment: Any specific reason you are using a Custom Runnable instead of just using a Runnable?

Comment: Well, you're violating the single threaded nature of Swing to start with

Comment: Exactly as @MadProgrammer states -- you're making Swing calls from within a background thread, not good or safe. Use a `SwingWorker<String, Void>` instead

Comment: I don't think the UI is "freezing" so much as there is a delay between when the file been read and the text becoming available, but I'm guessing

Comment: Sorry, I just don't know any other methods how to read a file and set a text to JTextArea in another thread :) 
I will try to use a SwingWorker.

Comment: I tried to use SwingWorker - the same thing. Yeah, an app are not freezing but text are not available a long time and my PC start to freeze. 
I added a class FileReaderWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>. Added to "doInBackground" method my reader and set a text to JTextArea via the "done" method. I also added to readButton AL new FileReaderWorker().execute();. And again after using reader1 the text available immediately, but after using reader2 the text are not available and It can't added to my textArea.

Comment: `"/path/to/6.3MBfile"` What good (to the user) is 6.3 megabytes of text?

Comment: It was a .osm file - kind of xml file.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is the performance for code half way between the examples - use `BufferedReader.read()` instead of `BufferedReader.readLine()`. I assume it'll have performance in the same ballpark, although there is overhead doing UTF-8 decoding.

Next up you are allocating a `String` each time. That's not good. Just reading a chunk with `Reader.read(char[])` would be much better. Further `BufferedReader.readLine()` isn't very efficient, in addition to allocating the `String` it may also allocate a `StringBuffer` complete with internals **every time it is call**. `java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines` is an easy and efficient way to load a file if you want all strings, though it will be all `String`s.

The huge turnover of memory will be what is causing all threads to have problems.

Comment: I used BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)) and I get the same thing with no available text. BufferedReader successfully read a file even with a UTF-8 decoding. I tried to debug it and realized that my program stops at "textArea.setText(text)".

Comment: I made a random 90k strings file with 5x UUIDs in 1 string. And all works good. I didn't understand it because it depends on file... I previously tried to read a 83k strings .osm (open street map) file. It is kind of xml file.

Comment: `Files.readAllLines` is an easy way to read all lines, but since it simply calls `readLine()` on a `BufferedReader`, it provides no performance improvement at all, as it still creates the same objects as `reader2()`, but additionally fills an `ArrayList` that has to get converted to the final `String` then. @global_silence: keep in mind that `readLine()` returns the line without line breaks. So `reader2()` differs from `reader1()` in that it eliminates all line breaks, creating a single humongous line. A lot of software has problems with overlong lines, especially editors with line wrapping.